# Как убрать папку из удаленного репозитория

Tags: git, repository

На протяжении нескольких коммитов я тащил с собой лишнюю папку размером в десятки мегабайт, а одумался уже когда сделал пуш и увидел ту самую папку в веб интерфейсе. Я смело спрятал папку за всевидящее око git'а и сделал еще один пуш, папка больше не отображается, но мне говорят, что размер репозитория (размер в мегабайтах который) увеличился и в этом моя вина. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как теперь безболезненно убрать эту папку с удаленного репозитория?

Comment: Я бы ещё заметил, что если вы не главный по проекту, то лучше такое решение самостоятельно не принимать, т.к. если вы сделаете push --force не вовремя, вам это не только в вину поставят, но могут ещё и почки отбить.

Comment: Комментарий по поводу дубликата: да, я вижу, что тот был задан позднее. Но там ответ есть, а тут - нет.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен filter-branch:

https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data
http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/2-permanently-remove-files-and-folders-from-a-git-repository

Comment: Тут спорная ситуация. Ваш ответ как бы неполный, но верный. Есть совсем недавно заданный вопрос-копия, но там ответ полнее. Что делать с этим? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/426401/181472

Comment: Да что хотите, я-то чего