# Как удалить файл из истории Git?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

Не могу полностью удалить файл из истории Git.

Файл - бинарник с русским названием, и так получилось что пришлось чуть исправить его название - изменить регистр пары букв.
Сделал коммит, залил на GitHub. Теперь и в консоли и в gui git'a "висит" сообщение что файл со старым названием удален. Удалить через консоль нельзя - файл не существует, отмена изменений в gui ни к чему не приводит - через несколько секунд сообщение снова появляется. После новых коммитов ничего не меняется. На диске файла нет. ОС - Win8.

Я хотел бы полностью удалить файл из истории (т.е. из всех коммитов, где он упоминается). Как это сделать?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Вам надо файл удалить или Вам мешает то, что его нет? Изменение только регистра в WIndows не приводит к смене имени, т.к. NTFS нечувствителен к регистру. В связи с этим можно получить много головной боли если не использовать в этом случае переименование средствами git: `git mv --force file File`

Comment: Файла нет, git все время говорит что он удален. Переименовать файл невозможно, так как его нет. Пробовал удалить из истории, но это не помогает.

Comment: можно откатиться до той версии, где он есть: `git reset <commit_id>` и там его переименовать

Comment: Либо сделать `git revert` тех изменений, которые были представлены коммитом, удалившим файл, а потом его переименовать

Comment: @ixSci Пожалуйста, перенесите ваши комментарии в ответ.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, я подожду ответа автора, т.к. я до сих пор не очень понимаю, что у него происходит, поэтому не могу дать точного ответа.

Comment: @ixSci, хоть ваши советы и не помогли, благодарю за участие.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669686/178988

Answer (score 15, accepted):

В документации GitHub отлично описан этот кейс: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/

Сначала делаем

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch <myfile>' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

заменяем `<myfile>` на название файла который нужно вычистить из репы. Затем:

```
git push origin --force --all
git push origin --force --tags
```

Comment: Да, это именно то что нужно. Я пробовал эту команду, но мне не хватало последних аргументов, и история о файле оставалась. Большое спасибо.

Comment: А как после этого правильно pull сделать в другое хранилище, чтобы файл обратно не попал?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669686/178988