# Удаление истории на github

Tags: git, github

Ситуация следующая :
На github был добавлен нежелательный файл и в последствии удален.
Но в истории, которая отображается на гите он висист, и вся информация которая хранится в нем доступна.
Как можно удалить все что связано с этим файлом с гита?(в том числе и историю).

[Как удалить файл из истории Git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426401/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-git][1])

Пробовал точно как описано в статье, все равно ничего неудаляеться, хотя в консоль пишет что все ок.

Comment: [tsya.ru](http://tsya.ru)

Comment: приведите весь набор команд, которые вы выполняете (включая те, которые показывают наличие файла в истории после чистки)

Comment: `git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
Rewrite 6ed26450b7db3b5dea7ae8917ce20e70ab19ea43 (5/5)
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged` 
После ввода `git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch <myfile>` ничего непроисходит, и в конце при вводе `--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`  "--prune-empty" появляеться надпись -  не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.