# Удалить файл из репозитория

Tags: git

Загрузил в удаленный репозиторий (github) файл с кодами application.yml.
Как мне удалить его оттуда и перестать отслеживать изменения на нем?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/426401/178576

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Добавьте файл в `.gitignore`
2. `git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch application.yml` - удаляем файл только из репозитория, и физически файл сохранится на диске
3. `git commit -am "Message"`
4. `git push origin {branch name}`

Comment: Выполнил вторую команду. Файл удалился вообще, мне из репозитория надо удалить, а на диске оставить.

Comment: Удалять файл с диска он не должен, но ответ я дополнил

Answer (score 2):

Удалить у себя и сделать commit и push. И, таки да, не удалить, а в .gitignore его

Comment: Сначала удалить, а потом в .gitignore. Иначе не поможет.