# Некорректное отображение файлов, в названиях которых есть русские буквы

Tags: git

Старый проект перенесли на новый сервер git. При клонировании из сервера git на клиентскую машину с tortoise Git старые файлы отображаются крякозябриками, а новые нормально сохраняются на русском языке. 
Старые файлы заново создал и сохранил. Новые файлы нормально запушились (push) на сервер, но в истории также отображаются старые файлы с козябриками.

- Пытался в коммите указать skip worktree, выдает ошибку  "libgit2 returned: Index does not contain "название файла с козябриками"".
- Попробовал удалить и закоммитить, однако во время коммита статус файла пишет  "missing" и коммит (commit) не происходит с ошибкой "no changes added to commit". Т.е. теперь нужно удалить каким то образом из истории эти файлы.
- Попробовал в ignore list добавить но не добавляется, предполагаю из за того что не может разобрать название файла.

Дополнение: сервер git 2.7.4 установлен на linux ubuntu 16.04 TLS, locale lang = en_US.UTF-8, LANGUAGE=en. На клиентской стороне windows 7, tortoise git 2.2.0.0, git version 2.8.1.windows.1. язык и региональные стандарты указан Русский (Россия)

Comment: Похоже на разные настройки локали на старом и новом сервере.

Comment: @AK, т.к. программа git запускается локально, то, скорее всего, разные настройки как раз на локальных машинах, а не на сервере.

Comment: попробуйте `git rm` на файлах «с крякозябрами»

Answer (score 1):

для переименования файлов с сохранением истории их изменений можно воспользоваться командой *mv* программы *git*:

```
$ git mv файл.с.неправильным.названием файл.с.правильным.названием
```

команда *status* после этого покажет изменения, внесённые (пока) в индекс:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    renamed:    файл.с.неправильным.названием -> файл.с.правильным.названием
```

эти изменения надо закоммитить командой *commit*, и, при необходимости, отправить на сервер командой *push*:

```
$ git commit
$ git push
```

---

а если файл надо просто удалить из хранилища, то можно воспользоваться командой *rm*:

```
$ git rm файл
```

после чего это изменение надо закоммитить и, при необходимости, отправить на сервер.

---

если же требуется удалить и упоминания файла в истории, то можно воспользоваться ответом на этот вопрос: [Как удалить файл из истории Git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/426401/178576) (но при изменнении истории совместно используемого репозитория это действие, по-моему, малопродуктивно).

Comment: он УЖЕ переименовал файлы, ему надо удалить старые

Comment: @ixSci, ну, я ориентировался на решение изначальной проблемы. но добавил и про *rm*.