# удалить из Git файл большого размера попавший туда несколько коммитов назад

Tags: java, git, github, jar

Опыт java и Git ~1 месяц, ОС linux mint.

Нужна ваша помощь:

1.В начале забыл добавить в .gitignore папку target/ в которой хранятся скомпилированные *.jar *.class и прочие файлы.
2.позже через несколько коммитов обнаружил что папка .git весит 12+ мегабайт, по размеру предполагаю что это забытый мной jar файл (кода у меня ~15 килобайт, все .class файлы ~14 килобайт)
3.нашел этот файл руками он весит 12 МБ и лежит в папке

```
.git/objects/pack/pack-2af1dfb851dabe3d606e0d0f9ad7ba84fd74f043.idx
```

Прошел несколько вопросов на русском и английском stackoverflow + google
пробовал следующее:

1. git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch
   FILENAME' --prune-empty -- --all
2. git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch
   FILENAME' HEAD
3. git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached
   --ignore-unmatch FILENAME' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

Вместо FILENAME пробовал подставлять вот это:

- target/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar
- gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar
- target/
- *.jar

толку не дало.

В итоге у меня 2 вопроса:
-Как выяснить что это весит 12МБ в папке .git и как это удалить?

вот [ссылка](https://github.com/jiraff537/tic-tac-toe-RESTfulWebService) на мо проект на github, можно скачать как zip-архив или клонировать:

```
git clone https://github.com/jiraff537/tic-tac-toe-RESTfulWebService.git
```

(да я пытаюсь написать Rest-бэкэнд на Spring Boot'e для крестиков-ноликов)

Comment: Скажите, а вам очень дороги эти несколько коммитов с момента, когда вы файл закоммитили? Так-то можно просто откатиться (`rebase -i` или `reset --soft`) и заменить их все новым коммитом.

Comment: @NickVolynkin дело в том что я хочу научиться решать такую проблему. на работу устраиваюсь juniur-ом. хочу разобраться в вопросе (коммиты сносить я уже научился)

Comment: благое намерение! :)

Comment: На самом деле, 12 метров в репозитории - это очень немного. Говорю вам как видевший двухгигабайтный репозиторий...

Comment: @PavelMayorov раз уж настало время страшных историй: репозиторий thirdparty, в нем сорцы всех библиотек на c++, используемых хотя бы в одном проекте в большой айтишной компании. Штук 50 их там было, места тоже гига полтора, но из-за количества файлов `git clone`  творил непотребство с disk io.

Comment: @NickVolynkin это вы меня не в #адЪ отправили? :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov да я догадываюсь что 12М это мелочи, хочу **научиться и понять.** внизу вон мне ответили развернуто, ночером/утром буду делать.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

вы можете посмотреть содержимое каталога `target` (во всех коммитах):

```
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'ls -l target'
Rewrite c05ea07d436c9e6c96f9e441bd469ae89d6383b4 (1/29)total 14056
drwxr-xr-x 3 user user     4096 May 23 14:27 classes
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 14352691 May 23 14:27 gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     3829 May 23 14:27 gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar.original
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user     4096 May 23 14:27 maven-archiver
drwxr-xr-x 3 user user     4096 May 23 14:27 maven-status
...
```

или информацию о конкретном файле `target/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar`:

```
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'ls -l target/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar'
Rewrite c05ea07d436c9e6c96f9e441bd469ae89d6383b4 (1/29)
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 14352691 May 23 14:29 target/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar
...
```

удалить файл во всех коммитах можно, например, так:

```
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f target/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar'
Rewrite f2133e7b3d7f209f43e88b802a6589cb2a1eadfd (29/29)
Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
```

---

после такого переписывания истории в своём локальном репозитории вам придётся перезаписать историю и в репозитории на сайте `github.com`, добавив опцию `-f` (`--force`) команде `push`:

```
$ git push -f
```

---

p.s. если репозиторий был склонирован ещё куда-то/кем-то, то там/тому надо будет принудительно переключиться на отправленную вами переписанную историю:

```
$ git fetch
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

или просто заново склонировать репозиторий в пустой каталог.

---

> как это удалить?

<strike>после того, как вы перезаписали историю, объект типа *blob*, содержащий удалённый файл, стал «осиротевшим». чтобы удалить его, надо воспользоваться командой `gc` (*gargabe collection*):</strike>

```
$ git gc
Counting objects: 500, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (222/222), done.
Writing objects: 100% (500/500), done.
Total 500 (delta 221), reused 413 (delta 172)
```

как показывает вывод команды `$ du -sb .git` (выполненной до и после `$ git gc`), занимаемый каталогом `.git` объём изменился на 242997 байт (13254649-13011652). вероятно, именно столько занимал удалённый файл (в сжатом виде).

после того, как вы перезаписали свою локальную историю, удалённый файл (пока) не стал «осиротевшим» — на него есть ссылки из (пока не переписанной) истории подключенного репозитория (который на github-е находится). после того, как вы перепишете историю и на github-е, команда

```
$ git gc
```

должна будет удалить объект типа *blob*, содержащий этот «осиротевший» файл.

#### дополнение

полную очистку и упаковку всех объектов, чтобы добиться минимального размера каталога `.git`, можно выполнить примерно так:

```
$ git gc; git prune; git repack -ad
```

ваш репозиторий (т.е., содержимое каталога `.git`), после удаления того большого файла, и полной переупаковки, стал занимать у меня 187165 байт.