# Git репозиторий вырос в размере после сбора мусора

Tags: git, контроль-версий, repository

Доброго времени суток.

Столкнулся с проблемой после выполнения git gc --aggressive
размер репозитория вырос с 700 метров до 5.2Гб

Перепробовал следующие варианты

```
git gc --prune=now --aggressive

git repack

git reflog expire --expire=now --all
```

в разной последовательности реакции никакой.

в `.git/objects/pack` лежит множество файлов `pack-{hash}.(idx|pack)` размером около 100мб всего около 50 пар (idx, pack)

Объем данных всего 235мб изменения по этому репозитория были небольшие около 100мб за все время может быть и изменилось, ну фиг с ним допустим изменений на 1гб но никак не 5гб.

Сейчас посмотрел реп в bitbucket весит 287.4MB

подскажите хоть в какую сторону копать... очень не хочется переиничивать весь реп.

**Дополнение**

Может поможет для анализа проблемы во время работы git gc --aggressive уперся в дисковую квоту было около 30 файлов .tmp-pack... которые я грохнул текущие pack файлы все в порядке проверил так `git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx | grep pack`

---

Всем отбой, вопрос пока перестал быть актуальным, т.к. в виду запоротого репа пришлось его переинитить =(

Но поскольку это у же не первый раз когда после `git gc --aggressive` реп разрастается до гигантских размеров причем именно локальный, любой клон из такого репа весит столько сколько и ожидается в мб прошлый раз был реп 100мб который без сбора мусора разросся до 6Гб что нормально (т.к. были очень частые коммиты и реп не обслуживался почти год), а после git gc стал вестить 11Гб, возможно понадобиться помощь коллективного разума =)

Comment: а что пишет git gc при выполнении? ничего похожего на failed to unlink в логах нет?

Comment: в том то и проблема что нет ни одной ошибки сейчас вот прошелся git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx  все pack в норме проблем нет, но размер 5гб =(

Comment: буквально только что дополнял свой ответ к соседнему вопросу. [смотрите после слова «дополнение»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669686/178576)

Comment: вы делали заново клонирование в пустой каталог? а то ведь в репозитории могут сохраняться ссылки на объекты, которые в другом репозитории (на bitbucket) могут отсутствовать.

Comment: alexander barakin внутри нет ни одного репозитория, на этом я уже вчера обжегся... там только файлы... и суть именно в том что размер вырос именно после команды git gc --aggressive т.е. до ее выполнения он весил около 400мб (700мб это с учетом файлов) а сразу же после стал весить 5гб ни одного коммита между 400мб и 5гб не было.

Comment: alexander barakin еще сейчас на выполнение ваша магическая последовательность `git gc; git prune; git repack -ad` поэтому пока склонировать именно оттуда не могу, а в bitbucket я уже говорил размер менее 300метров.

Comment: опять забыл увеличить дисковую квоту в итоге запорол реп =( `git status` возвращает fatal: bad object HEAD

Comment: 1. чтобы пользователь получил уведомление о комментарии, надо упомянуть его так `@имя` (трёх уникальных первых букв будет достаточно, но вообще после ввода `@` сразу предлагаются варианты подстаноки). 2. в каталоге `.git` находится именно репозиторий (обычно я предпочитаю русское слово «хранилище»). те файлы/каталоги, которые вы наблюдаете **рядом** с каталогом `.git` — это всего лишь **рабочая копия** содержимого репозитория.

Comment: `git gc --aggressive` пережимает все существующие pack в новые, и после этого удаляет старые. судя по всему, у вас старые не удаляются. неизвестно почему. может просто баг в той версии гита, которой вы пользуетесь.

Comment: @PashaPash ... или просто привычка что-то делать рутом и потом удивляться правам.

Comment: @zb' не совсем понятно с чего вы взяли что проблема с правами? Тем более когда я уже указал в чем была проблема...

Comment: @fens мне кажется, ваш ответ удален... О, так это не вами...

Answer (score 2):

Сегодня снова столкнулся с этой же проблемой на той же машине, снова репозиторий размером до 500мб вырос до 7Гб сразу же насторожил размер паков опять те самые 100мб в итоге глянув конфиг нашел это `pack.packsizelimit=100m` на другой машине где наблюдалась схожая проблема стоит `pack.packsizelimit=20m` удаление этого параметра из конфига решило проблему. (Как всегда все оказалось проще чем можно было представить.)

На сколько я понял просто git в каждый новый пак засовывает полную версию файлов последнего коммита поместившегося в предыдущий пак. Отсюда если имеем 90мб sql и дельты к нему из ~4000 коммитов, тогда получается в оставшиеся 10мб влезали только дельты из 48-50коммитов.

Итого: если у вас git репозиторий вырос намного больше чем суммарный вес файлов в рабочем дереве после git gc и вы видите в .git/objects/pack множество pack файлов это значит что чьи то шаловливые ручонки выставили параметр `pack.packsizelimit` в конфеге, можете смело его грохнуть, т.к. по дефолту он не определен и нужен только для специфичных фс где есть ограничение на максимальный размер файла.