# Как удалить файлы из уже сделанного комита?

Tags: git

У меня есть git репозиторий, с программой, в который я случайно добавил куча видео очень давно.  Сами видео уже были давно удалены, я удалял их из гита (`git rm ExampleResult`) (Все они лежат в папке ExampleResult). Но проблема возникла когда я попытался это все залить на гитхаб, так как теперь репозиторий весит около 90 ГБ и любые манипуляции проводить с ним очень долго. (С пушем я сдался на строке Compressing Objects). Что можно сделать что бы это исправить.

git ls-files выдаёт

```
.gitignore
README.md
config.py
main.py
requirements.txt
video_divider.py
```

#### Попытка фильтрации:

```
(venv) git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf *.mp4' HEAD
WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history
         rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an
         alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo'
         (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.  See the
         filter-branch manual page for more details; to squelch this warning,
         set FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1.
Proceeding with filter-branch...

usage: git filter-branch [--setup <command>] [--subdirectory-filter <directory>] [--env-filter <command>]
        [--tree-filter <command>] [--index-filter <command>]
        [--parent-filter <command>] [--msg-filter <command>]
        [--commit-filter <command>] [--tag-name-filter <command>]
        [--original <namespace>]
        [-d <directory>] [-f | --force] [--state-branch <branch>]
        [--] [<rev-list options>...]
```

Как я понял это значит что команда не выполнилась. Папка .git до сих пор весит под 100 Гб.

Так же пытался удалить всю директорию ExampleResult в которой все файлы и находятся, но это не увенчалось успехом.

```
>git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch ExampleResult' HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'rm': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [удалить из Git файл большого размера попавший туда несколько коммитов назад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/669670/%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-git-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4)

Comment: `git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch ExampleResult` — это чего за бред? вам же просто удалить каталог надо: `rm -rf ExampleResult`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это происходит потому, что история (history) имеет эту запись и Гит "обязан" иметь эти файлы во время `push`.
Поэтому надо удалить их из истории:

`git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf *.avi' HEAD`

где:

-rf рекурсив и форсед
-avi расширение файла, как вы уже догадались сами.

Последующие `push`-ы должны исключить эти файлы

Comment: в вопросе написано: `Все они лежат в папке ExampleResult`. а вы что написали в примере команды?

Comment: `-r` не нужно, вы же файлы удаляет, а не каталоги.