# Отправка части существующего репозитория в новый

Tags: git

У меня есть локальный git-репозиторий, в котором я делаю свой небольшой проект.
Хотелось бы выложить на bitbucket/github его часть (пока не хочу выкладывать целиком в открытый доступ, мб получиться заработать на нём).

Вопрос в том, как выложить только один модуль/файл, а не весь проект? И при этом сохранить авторство/историю коммитов. Т.е. обычный push all на новый репозиторий не прокатит

Comment: [`filter-branch`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/426401/178576)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/olavmrk/9383860

Comment: Спасибо! жалко не в отдельном посте ответ, галочку б поставил

Comment: зря вы ответ удалили. *ответ* должен быть оформлен как ответ, а не как дополнение к тексту вопроса. восставите его, пожалуйста. только поправьте форматирование и укажите источник на гитхабе.