# ошибка загрузки на GitHub

Tags: git, github

При загрузке проекта на Github с помощью GitHub Desktop появляется следующая ошибка:

```
The push operation includes a file which exceeds GitHub's file size restriction of 100MB. Please remove the file from history and try again.
```

Я удалил из проекта файлы более 100 MB и сделал

```
git rm <file_name>
```

Закомитил все изменения. В результате был небольшой прогресс загрузки, но ошибка повторилась и репозиторий на GitHub пустой.
Попытка загрузки через командную строку закончилась так:

```
git push origin master
error: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version while accessing https://github.com/VyacheslavLobanov/logparser.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

**Для справки:** я загружаю Django проект с Windows 10. Раньше загружал Java и проблем не было.
Что сделать, чтобы решить проблему?

Comment: Все файлы хранятся в истории гита, простое удаление файлов не удалит их из истории. Если в гите ничего ценного ещё нет, тупо пересоздайте его например

Comment: @andreymal, Дело в том, что у меня уже завершенный проект. Мне надо его только разместить. Можно ли удалить файлы по списку и как его получить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как удалить файл из истории Git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426401/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-git)

Comment: Если что, [**Git LFS**](https://git-lfs.github.com/) позволяет загружать файлы размером более 100 МБ. Спасибо.