# Как удалить папку с файлами из удаленного репозитория git?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-commit, git-push

У меня есть папка с файлами внутри проекта, которые не нужно было отправлять в удаленный репозиторий, но я забыл добавить эту папку в gitignore..
Уже отправил несколько коммитов на удаленный сервер.
Можно ли удалить эту папку из всех старых коммитов на сервере?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как удалить файл из истории Git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426401/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-git)